# Dynamic object with string properties

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have been working with custom dynamic objects, that access an underlying data row or dictionary, for example:

```
public class DictionaryX : DynamicObject
{
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dict;

        public DictionaryX(Dictionary<string, string> dict) { _dict = dict; }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            var retVal = _dict.ContainsKey(binder.Name);
            result = retVal ? _dict[binder.Name] : null;
            return retVal;
        }
 }
```

This makes reading and writing the code a lot easier, eg in the case of a DataRow

```
var fullName = row.Name + row.Surname;
```

Instead of

```
var fullName = row.Field("Name") + row("Surname");
```

But what we really want is for the accessed property to be type string instead of dynamic.  The data is always a string in the underlying object, but in places we have to cast as string or declare them as string instead of 'var', otherwise we can get compile or runtime errors eg when passing to other methods

```
string fullName = row.Name + row.Surname
DoSomething(fullName);
DoSomethingElse((string)row.Surname);
```

This undoes some of the work of making it nicer code to work with. I'd like to make an DynamicStringObject that allows me to write code in this way but accessed properties are always strings, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If your type is `dynamic`, any call on it must *necessarily* return something of type `dynamic`, because the compiler can not only not know what the returned type is, but it might actually change between calls at runtime! Use an ORM like Dapper if you want strong typing on the fly. Accessing stuff this way is massively inefficient to begin with; ORM libraries generally leverage dynamic code generation (not to be confused with `dynamic` itself, which is always fully dynamic) to get this done.

Comment: Can you give more context for where _dict is coming from and what the type is of row? Or perhaps you can paste code showing how you are actually trying to use this. 

Generally if you are trying to get typed access to fields then using T4 to emit typed accessors might work better than trying to use an untyped (or dynamically typed) approach.